# Fetch all vehicles having selected accessories

Tags: sql

There is a many-to-many relationship between **vehicles** (PK=v_id) and **accessories** (PK=a_id. There is a bridging table **vehicles_accessories** (PK=v_id,a_id).

Customer on the web page can select required accessories that vehicle must have and a query should select only vehicles having all these accessories. Number of accessories selected is variable. Ones a customer can select 2 accessories, other time 4 of them, etc.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select * from vehicles where v_id in
(
  select v.v_id
  from vehicles v
  join vehicle_accessories va on va.v_id=v.v_id
  where va.a_id in (32,34)
  group by v.v_id
  having count(*)=2
)
```

On page I collect accessories selected by customer and put them in IN clause with HAVING COUNT(*)=# of selected accessories.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have a join too many:

```
select v.*
from vehicles v
where v.v_id in (select va.v_id
                 from vehicle_accessories va
                 where va.a_id in (32, 34)
                 group by va.v_id
                 having count(*) = 2
                );
```

In some databases, it might be faster to use a `join` or `not exists`, but that depends on the particular database.